# SQL median of values less than a given date, month on month

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compute the median as a function of time with SQLAlchemy in python. What I am looking for is the median over all time below a given date.

So some example data is

```
Date       Value  
2017-08-02 0.11   
2017-08-22 0.34   
2017-08-24 0.66   
2017-09-05 1.23   
2017-09-26 0.15   
2017-10-07 0.99   
2017-10-13 1.01   
2017-10-22 0.44   
2017-10-28 0.89
```

What I want to compute is the median for all the values in August, then the median for all the values in August *and* September, then the median for all the values in August *and* September *and* October.

The sample output would be something like this.

```
Date       Median
2017-08-01 0.34  
2017-09-01 0.34  
2017-10-01 0.66
```

In the actual data there are many more values so the median is actually meaningful. I do not know in advance how many entries there will be per month.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) You are probably going to be better off using base SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that a better method exists, but you could select months from your data – represented by the maximum date in a group here – and then calculate the 50th percentile for each month  and below separately:

```
months = select([func.max(tbl.c.date).label('date')]).\
    group_by(func.date_trunc('month', tbl.c.date)).\
    alias('months')

percentiles = select([
        func.percentile_cont(0.5).
            within_group(tbl.c.value).
            label('median')]).\
    where(tbl.c.date <= months.c.date).\
    lateral('percentiles')

query = select([months.c.date,\
                percentiles.c.median]).\
    order_by(months.c.date)
```

the result being:

```
In [8]: engine.execute(query).fetchall()
2017-10-25 16:44:18,637 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT months.date, percentiles.median 
FROM (SELECT max(foo.date) AS date 
FROM foo GROUP BY date_trunc(%(date_trunc_1)s, foo.date)) AS months, LATERAL (SELECT percentile_cont(%(percentile_cont_1)s) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY foo.value) AS median 
FROM foo 
WHERE foo.date <= months.date) AS percentiles ORDER BY months.date
2017-10-25 16:44:18,637 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'percentile_cont_1': 0.5, 'date_trunc_1': 'month'}
Out[8]: 
[(datetime.date(2017, 8, 24), 0.34),
 (datetime.date(2017, 9, 26), 0.34),
 (datetime.date(2017, 10, 28), 0.66)]
```

Truncating the dates to 1st day of month should be pretty trivial, if required. Note that you could also just use a scalar subquery in place of the LATERAL.